# Get data between characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have files with these names in a table:

```
ar37_bescl_20160601_010645 (2).xml

ar37_bes_20160601_010645 (2).xml
```

However what interests me is just keeping the date. How can I do this throught SQL?

Result:

```
20160601

20160601
```

I've tried with substring, patindex and reverse and so far I haven't been able to.

Like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(FILENAME,8,8), FILENAME
FROM Table
```

Comment: Show what you have tried and the results / errors and we can help you to fix that or do it a better way.

Comment: Are you asking specifically for extracting the string of characters between the second and 3rd underscore? Or can the date apear anywhere in the string?

Comment: *"I've tried with substring, patindex and reverse"* include those attempts on your question; then we can tell you why they're not working.

Comment: @Stu Yes exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 3rd position, here is an option using a bit of JSON.

Note:  The `string_escape(...,'json')` is just precautionary.

**Example**

```
Select * 
      ,NewVal = JSON_VALUE('["'+replace(string_escape(SomeCol,'json'),'_','","')+'"]' ,'$[2]')
 From YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol                             NewVal
ar37_bescl_20160601_010645 (2).xml  20160601
ar37_bes_20160601_010645 (2).xml    20160601
```

**EDIT:** For a more robust approach you can use a `CROSS APPLY` to create the JSON string once.

```
Select A.SomeCol
      ,Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
      ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
      ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
      ,Pos4 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(replace(string_escape(SomeCOl,'json'),' ','_'),'_','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol                             Pos1    Pos2    Pos3        Pos4
ar37_bescl_20160601_010645 (2).xml  ar37    bescl   20160601    010645
ar37_bes_20160601_010645 (2).xml    ar37    bes     20160601    010645
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, if you can trust there is only one element in the string that represents a valid date, that also allows you to have a variable number of `_` separators before or after the date:

```
SELECT f.fname, s.value 
FROM dbo.files AS f
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(f.fname, '_') AS s
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, s.value, 112) IS NOT NULL;
```

(Actually you may *want* multiple rows back if there is more than one valid date in the string.)