# Splitting a SQL column's value into several fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of rows that have a field called "name" that have values like this, delimited by a _:

```
ServerNumber_BrandNumber_BrandName_JobName
```

Sometimes, the job name will be spread out over two deliminations, like this:

```
ServerNumber_BrandNumber_BrandName_JobName_JobNamePart2
```

I want to break out each of those into their own field in a select statement like this:

```
SELECT
    name[0] as ServerNumber,
    name[1] as BrandNumber,
    name[2] as BrandName,
    name[3] as JobName
from table
```

If I do something like this it will work if job name is only part of one delmiter, but it will return nothing if it's using two:

`REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(name), '_', '.'), 1))`

How can I do all of this?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is the character that is a delimiter is also being used as something that *isn't* a delimiter; is fixing the data an option?

Comment: Is JobName the only one which can have two separate parts?

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71414053/get-data-between-characters/71414162#71414162   Just concat Pos3 and Pos4

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Take a look at this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1353b1c08048da00a1996a7d95c382f6) (which shows `SELECT *
FROM STRING_SPLIT('ServerNumber_BrandNumber_BrandName_JobName_JobNamePart2','_');`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Name] varchar(150))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('ServerNumber_BrandNumber_BrandName_JobName')
,('ServerNumber_BrandNumber_BrandName_JobName_JobNamePart2')
 

 Select Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
       ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
       ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
       ,Pos4 = concat(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]'),'_'+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[4]'))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(replace(string_escape([Name],'json'),' ','_'),'_','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
Pos1            Pos2        Pos3        Pos4
ServerNumber    BrandNumber BrandName   JobName
ServerNumber    BrandNumber BrandName   JobName_JobNamePart2
```

**XML Approach  (2012)**

```
 Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(150)')
       ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(150)')
       ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(150)')
       ,Pos4 = concat(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(150)'),'_'+xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(150)'))
From  @YourTable A
Cross Apply ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(NAME,'_','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))  B(xDim)
```

Comment: is string_escape only available in certain versions? I'm using SQL Server 2012 and it's not available

Comment: @huzzakawah 2012 is a little dated (you should mention/tag your version ) .   See updated answer with an XML Approach

Comment: I'm sorry about the lack of info. This was my first post and now I know. Thank you very much! This worked perfectly.